# Grouping digits according to the Indian numbering system in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

`\num{100000}` prints 100 000

I want to have 1 00 000.

Question: How to set `siunitx` package to do the above?

Some more

`\num{1000}` => 1 000

`\num{10000}` => 10 000

`\num{100000}` => 1 00 000

`\num{1000000}` => 10 00 000

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}

\begin{document}

\num{1000}

\num{10000}

\num{100000}

\num{1000000}

\num{10000000}

\num{100000000}

\num{1000000000}

\SI{1000000000}{m}

\end{document}
```

The exact rules are described on the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Numbering_System):

> The Indian Numbering System uses separators differently from the Arabic system; besides the three least significant digits of the integer part, a comma divides every two rather than every three digits.

Comment: What are the precise rules?

Comment: It seems to be: the rightmost group is of three digits, the others are groups of two digits (or one for the first). It doesn't seem difficult to implement, but I suspect it needs a specific set of macros in `siunitx`.

Comment: The `siunitx` solution is available at [Customize grouping of digits using siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615075/4301). Normally the newer question should have been closed as a duplicate of this one, but as that already has answers, not sure it is worthwhile to bump this up.

Answer (score 14):

In the meantime before an actual `siunitx` solution arrives here, you can use this expandable macro. But it will work only on (long) integers. For numbers in scientific notation you need something which extracts the mantissa, and then you can feed `\indianum` with this mantissa.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}

\usepackage{xint}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\indianum[1]
    {\expandafter\indianum@\romannumeral-`0#1!}
\def\indianum@ #1{\ifx #1-\expandafter\@firstoftwo
                   \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                   {\expandafter-\romannumeral-`0\indianum@a}
                   {\indianum@a#1}}

\def\indianum@a #1!{\expandafter\indianum@b\expandafter
                    {\romannumeral-`0\xintLength{#1}}#1!}

\def\indianum@b #1{\xintifGt {#1}{3}
                        {\xintifOdd {#1}{\indianum@codd }
                                        {\indianum@ceven }}
                        {\indianum@short}}


\def\indianum@short #1!{#1}

\def\indianum@codd #1#2#3#4{\indianum@loop {#1#2,}{#3#4}}

\def\indianum@ceven #1#2#3{\indianum@loop {#1,}{#2#3}}

\def\indianum@loop #1#2#3#4{\ifx #4!\expandafter\@firstoftwo
                            \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                            {#1#2#3}{\indianum@loop {#1#2,}{#3#4}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\indianum{1}

\indianum{10}

\indianum{100}

\indianum{1000}

\indianum{10000}

\indianum{100000}

\indianum{1000000}

\indianum{10000000}

\indianum{100000000}

\indianum{1000000000}

\indianum{-1}

\indianum{-10}

\indianum{-100}

\indianum{-1000}

\indianum{-10000}

\indianum{-100000}

\indianum{-1000000}

\indianum{-10000000}

\indianum{-100000000}

\indianum{-1000000000}

\end{document}
```

> [image: indian numbering]

---

2017 edit (converted from a comment)

It is possible to load only `xintkernel` which is very small subset of `xint`, containing its `\xintLength` macro, and load `etoolbox` for its integer comparison conditionals in replacement of the `\xintifGt` and `\xintifOdd` conditionals of `xint`, the tested numbers being short enough certainly.

As `etoolbox` is often in use, this may be useful if the macros of `xint` are not needed elsewhere (and it is even possible to simply copy over from `etoolbox` package its definitions of `\ifnumgreater`  and `\ifnumodd` which are slim wrappers of TeX primitives; then only package `xintkernel` is needed.)

Here is the modified example, produces same output:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xintkernel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\indianum[1]{\expandafter\indianum@\romannumeral-`0#1!}

\def\indianum@ #1{\ifx #1-\expandafter\@firstoftwo
                   \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                   {\expandafter-\romannumeral-`0\indianum@a}
                   {\indianum@a#1}}

\def\indianum@a #1!{\expandafter\indianum@b\expandafter
                    {\romannumeral-`0\xintLength{#1}}#1!}

\def\indianum@b #1{\ifnumgreater {#1}{3}
                        {\ifnumodd {#1}{\indianum@codd }
                                       {\indianum@ceven }}
                        {\indianum@short}}

\def\indianum@short #1!{#1}

\def\indianum@codd #1#2#3#4{\indianum@loop {#1#2,}{#3#4}}

\def\indianum@ceven #1#2#3{\indianum@loop {#1,}{#2#3}}

\def\indianum@loop #1#2#3#4{\ifx #4!\expandafter\@firstoftwo
                            \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                            {#1#2#3}{\indianum@loop {#1#2,}{#3#4}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\indianum{1}

\indianum{10}

\indianum{100}

\indianum{1000}

\indianum{10000}

\indianum{100000}

\indianum{1000000}

\indianum{10000000}

\indianum{100000000}

\indianum{1000000000}

\indianum{-1}

\indianum{-10}

\indianum{-100}

\indianum{-1000}

\indianum{-10000}

\indianum{-100000}

\indianum{-1000000}

\indianum{-10000000}

\indianum{-100000000}

\indianum{-1000000000}

\end{document}
```