# Formatting numbers the Indian way

Tags: formatting, siunitx, calculations, indic

This is a follow-up question to [Handling numbers and calculations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214036/handling-numbers-and-calculations).

The numbers printed by `\num[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]{\the\numexpr(5000)\relax}` will produce comma separated numbers in groups of three digits each.

In India, however, we group numbers differently. Ones, Tens and Hundreds is the only group of three digits. All other groups are of two digits each.

The following example illustrates the difference:

- 123,456 gets written as 1,23,456
- 1,234,567 gets written as 12,34,567
- 12,345,678 gets written as 1,23,45,678
- 123,456,789 gets written as 12,34,56,789

Is there any way to get latex to format the numbers Indian way?

Comment: I think this has already been asked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144976/grouping-digits-according-to-the-indian-numbering-system-in-siunitx

Comment: There's an open feature request for this but it certainly will not happen before v3. Moreover, I'm still very wary of this as the entire 'three digit grouping' business is an international standard.

Comment: The `siunitx` solution is available at [Customize grouping of digits using siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615075/4301). Normally the newer question should have been closed as a duplicate of this one, but as that already has answers, not sure it is worthwhile to bump this up.