# siunitx: group decimal part of a number in two instead of three

Tags: siunitx

The following question has probably already been answered on this site but I can't find anything in the questions/answers archive.

How to I use [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to group the decimal part of a number in two instead of three?

I've searched through the manual but I couldn't find anything regarding this exact issue.

Comment: related comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214413/formatting-numbers-the-indian-way?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment502860_214413

Comment: a non-siunitx, but related solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144976/grouping-digits-according-to-the-indian-numbering-system-in-siunitx

Comment: @samcarter I have seen these questions but they are not exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *both* the decimal and the integer part in groups of two that can be done with the options `digit-group-first-size=2,  digit-group-other-size=2`.  However, if you want different grouping for the two parts then need a macro that seprates the integer and decimal parts and applies the desired settings to both parts:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numI}[1]{%
    \StrBehind{#1}{.}[\@DecimalPart]%
    \StrBefore{#1}{.}[\@IntegerPart]%
    \num[
        digit-group-first-size=3,  digit-group-other-size=3,
    ]{\@IntegerPart}%
    \num[
        digit-group-first-size=2,  digit-group-other-size=2,
    ]{.\@DecimalPart}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    $\numI{123456789.123456789}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Opps, there is a problem with this: The `siunitx` package adds a leading `0` if no digits are given in the integer part. Thus, there is an extra `0` in the ouptut number that was not in the input. I don't see an option to have the `num` macro to suppress that leading `0`.