# Currency group separators for India

Tags: siunitx

I am typesetting some Indian currency using spreadtab for calculations. I want to obey the usual conventions followed in typesetting Indian money amounts:

1. One thousand (hazar) = 1,000
2. One lakh = 1,00,000.
3. One crore = 1,00,00,000.
4. One urb = 1,00,00,00,000.
5. One khurb = 1,00,00,00,00,000.

The last two mentioned are uncommon. People prefer to say Rs 77,000 Cr. instead of Rs 770 urb.

This is unlike most other currencies (including German/British/US currencies) where you have uniform separators after every n (usually 3) zeros.

In Indian currency, the separators are after every two zeros, except for the first set, which is after three zeros.

I have looked at the documentation of numprint, but I do not think it can be done using that package (or siunitx for that matter).

Suggestions?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144976/grouping-digits-according-to-the-indian-numbering-system-in-siunitx help?